# How to use gloabal variable in javascript?

Tags: javascript, variables, global-variables

I am using JS to fetch some data through Axios. I want that response data outside the axios body. I have declared a global (let) var `tagData` outside the block. when I am logging value of `tagData` outside the axios its showing undefined.
how can I access the `response.data` outside axios block?

```
let data = ""
let tagData;
let movie;

const section = document.createElement('section');
section.setAttribute('class', 'section');
const container = document.createElement('div')
container.setAttribute('class', 'container is-desktop')



axios.get('https://dashletter-backend.herokuapp.com/blog/?category=allcategory')
    .then((response) => {
        tagData = response.data;
        console.log(tagData[0].name)
        for (movie in tagData) {
            const tagme = document.createElement('span')
            tagme.setAttribute('class', "tag is-rounded")
            tagme.setAttribute('id', "t" + movie)
            tagme.textContent = tagData[movie].name
            tagu.appendChild(tagme)

        }
    }
        , (error) => {
            console.log(error);

        });

console.log(tagData[0].name);  // Here tagData is undefined
```

Comment: It's because `console.log(tagData` executed before the promise is resolved which sets the value of `tagData`.

Comment: @vatz88 so where to put console.log?

Comment: Well, you should check out how promises work and asynchronous code is executed. You can put the log immediately after you set tagData or chain another then() and log it in there